# Web app not serving correctly after Angular 10 to Angular 13 migration (baseHref issue?)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

We have an Ionic application which we have just migrated from Ionic 5 to Ionic 6 and Angular 10 to Angular 13.  The app is served on the web as well as deployed to the native Android and iOS Stores.

When we deploy to the web server the app does not load and we get errors.  The problem seems to be that the **baseHref** setting in our angular.json file is now being ignored.

In angular.json we have one configuration for our device builds and one for our web builds.  In the web build configuration we have this:

```
"baseHref": "/web/"
```

This works find when we deploy out Ionic 5 / Angular 10 web files but when we deploy the migrated app we get errors loading asset files where it tries to load from

```
https://server-name/styles.7a9185c86c702a3f.css
```

where it should be loading from

```
https://server-name/web/styles.7a9185c86c702a3f.css
```

I can't find any documentation anywhere for Angular 11, 12 or 13 that suggests there was a breaking change for this.  Does anyone know what I need to do in my angular.json file to get this to work?

Comment: Did you check if index.html actually contains that basehref??.

Comment: Can you try to run the build with --baseHref  "/web/" param?? `npx ng buid --prod --baseHref "/web/"`

Comment: Actually I did not think to check!  I just checked and it's not there (the app loads fine if I insert it manually).  We don't build the app locally - we build it on AppFlow (Ionic's cloud build platform) - I'm not sure if I am able to add that flag, I will take a look - thanks

Comment: First i would to try it locally to see if there is any effect and / or if it is working for me locally without that switch or not - to narrow down what could be the culprit